# How can I use YANG Compiler to convert Yang to Java?

Tags: java, maven, sdn, onos, yang

I am trying to generate Java code from Yang using the ONOS YANG Compiler.
I'm following the instructions on the Wiki to compile, but I'm getting compile errors and cannot generate Java code from Yang.

[YANG Compiler](https://wiki.onosproject.org/display/ONOS/YANG+Compiler)

The following is the error message.

●Version :

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.2 (ea98e05a04480131370aa0c110b8c54cf726c06f)
Maven home: C:\tools\apache-maven-3.8.2
Java version: 1.8.0_202, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\pleiades\java\8\jre
Default locale: ja_JP, platform encoding: MS932
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_311"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode)
```

●pom.xml :

```
<!-- pom.xml -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <groupId>jp.co.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test_yang</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>onos-yang-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.onosproject/onos-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>onos-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.scr -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>onos-yang-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <yangFilesDir>src/main/yang</yangFilesDir>
                            <classFileDir>src/main/java</classFileDir>
                         </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yang2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

●Dir：

```
└─test_yang
    ├─pom.xml
    │  
    ├─src
    │  └─main
    │      ├─java
    │      └─yang
    │          ├─ openconfig-terminal-device.yang
    │          └─ test.yang
    │              
    └─target
        ├─classes
        └─test-classes
```

●error message

```
$ mvn clean install -X

...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.789 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-02T20:14:21+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.onosproject:onos-yang-maven-plugin:1.9:yang2java (default) on project test_yang: Execution default of goal org.onosproject:onos-yang-maven-plugin:1.9:yang2java failed: Unexpected internal error near index 1
[ERROR] \
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.onosproject:onos-yang-maven-plugin:1.9:yang2java (default) on project test_yang: Execution default of goal org.onosproject:onos-yang-maven-plugin:1.9:yang2java failed: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.onosproject:onos-yang-maven-plugin:1.9:yang2java failed: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error (Pattern.java:1957)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile (Pattern.java:1704)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init> (Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile (Pattern.java:1028)
    at java.lang.String.split (String.java:2380)
    at java.lang.String.split (String.java:2422)
    at org.onosproject.yangutils.utils.io.impl.YangIoUtils.getDirectory (YangIoUtils.java:294)
    at org.onosproject.yangutils.plugin.manager.YangUtilManager.execute (YangUtilManager.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Am I using the YANG Compiler incorrectly?

If you know anything about it, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is my pom

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
<artifactId>onos-yang-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.11</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <configuration>
            <classFileDir>src/main/java</classFileDir>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>yang2java</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <yangFilesDir>src/main/yang</yangFilesDir>
    <classFileDir>src/main/java</classFileDir>
</configuration>
```

and my pom doesn't have

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.onosproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>onos-yang-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
```